# Why is is ghidra representing mips move instruction as _or?

Tags: ghidra, mips

Now of course I keep trying to change it but once I get to the end of patching it says its invalid and wont let me change it. So if you have a way to do that let me know.

Comment: Think about carefully mov is just OR with a zero register

Comment: @PeterTeoh yes but I have never seen (or) be represented as (_or)

Comment: Ghidra uses `_` before an instruction to designate it is in a branch delay slot

Comment: @mumbel thanks brother I am still learning ghidra how would the branch delay slot be edited to give correct output example: or a0,v0,zero to move av0,v0 works great but in _or a0,s0,zero it ads och 04ch 0ch 04ch above it, now there doesnt appear to be a such thing as _move so how would that be rectified?

Comment: @PeterRobertson I would try clearing the branch instruction and the delay slot instruction, modify the delay slot instruction, and then re-disassemble both branch and delay slot instructions

Comment: @mumbel ok and being a newb how would I know which is the branch I looked at a few of them with instruction info and the only thing I see is : delay slot depth: 0 also is there a way to not have branch and delay slots automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Ghidra uses _ before an instruction to designate it is in a branch delay slot – mumbel 18 hours ago by @mumbel